# Can't map fetched data on first render in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have an API that returns me 4 objects and I try to save them in a new array called "products" and map them to the DOM. My problem is that map function doesn't work on first render.

If I modify something in my code, save the file and watch the react page again, I will see that my data appeared.

How can I fix that?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        products.push(data[i])
      }
    })
  })

  console.log(products);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {products.map((product,index) => (
        <div key={index}>{product.price}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function getdata() {      
      const res = await fetch("URL");
      const data = await res.json();
      setProducts(data)
    }

    let unmounted = false;    
    if (!unmounted) {
      getdata();
    }

    return () => unmounted = true;
}, []);
```

You can try this, I hope It will be work.

Comment: You are missing dependency array in your `useEffect` hook?

Comment: Thank you, I think he knew about dependency array

Comment: The `unmounted` check and cleanup function in this answer literally do nothing and you never set any data into `products` state so I have no idea how this is the accepted answer or how it got multiple upvotes

Answer (score 1):

You're directly mutating state which is a React no-no.

You need to use the `setProducts` state setter instead

```js
useEffect(() => {
  fetch("URL")
    .then(async res => {
      if (!res.ok) { // don't forget to check for errors
        throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
      }
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(setProducts) // pass the resolved data to the state setter
    .catch(console.error);
}, []); // use an empty dependency array to only run once on mount
```

Here's a demo using the [JSONPlaceholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/) `/albums` API

[image: Edit romantic-galois-0jvkzt]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are missing dependency array in your `useEffect` hook. Assuming you want the `useEffect` hook to run on initial render, I am passing empty dependency array (`[]`).

Next fix is you wait for your data to be set in products, and if products are set (that is you have a `products.length > 0`), you call

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => setProducts(data))
  }, [])

  console.log(products);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {products.length && products.map((product,index) => (
        <div key={index}>{product.price}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Iterating an empty array is the exact same result as _not_ iterating an empty array

Answer (score 0):

you have to run useEffect() only once
then u need to call setProducts

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("URL")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setProducts(data);
      })
  },[])
```

Answer (score -1):

The data is fetched after the first render.
You might want to use

```
{Boolean(products.length) && products.map((product,index) => (
    <div key={index}>{product.price}</div>
  ))}
```

and

```
useEffect(() => {
fetch("URL")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
  for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    products.push(data[i])
  }
  setProducts(products);
})
})
```

instead